# Xamarin.iOS NSString.StringSize wrong dimensions (sizeWithFont)

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, sizewithfont

I'm trying to calculate how much space string will take on screen.
I'm using NSString.StringSize (which now points to `sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:` in Xamarin.iOS)

```
UIFont MeasureFont = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(16f);
private static SizeF MaxMeasureSize = new SizeF(208, float.MaxValue);
//...
string messageBody = "Test";//comes from my dataSource
NSString nsString = new NSString(messageBody);
var textSize = nsString.StringSize(MeasureFont, MaxMeasureSize, UILineBreakMode.CharacterWrap);
Console.WriteLine("Measured -- {0} for [{1}]", textSize, messageBody);
```

Output in my app:

> 2014-09-05 00:05:20.338 App1[3150:90b] Measured -- {Width=29.68,
>   Height=19.088} for [Add]
>
> 2014-09-05 00:05:20.339 App1[3150:90b] Measured -- {Width=29.488,
>   Height=19.088} for [Test]

Screenshot with this font and these strings in PhotoShop.
Clearly, string 'Test' is longer than 'Add'

[image]

Comment: Are you testing it in simulator? I have just tried your example on iPad 3, and got following result: {Width=29,488, Height=19,088} for [Test] {Width=29,68, Height=19,088} for [Add]. And Test label is indeed just a bit smaller than Add label.

Comment: Also, StringSize is deprecated. You should use GetSizeUsingAttributes. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006893-CH3-SW7  https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/10016/measuring-string-width-getsizeusingattributes

Comment: I'm testing in simulator, you are right. 
Will check GetSizeUsingAttributes

Comment: The thing is that rendering can be different in simulator and in device. Plus, the fonts may be a bit different. Also, as I understand, you just typed these words directly in Photoshop to check the real width. This is incorrect too. The rendering in photoshop is definitely different.

Comment: I saw these words in the app and they are different length (test is longer). To double check I opened Photoshop and tried all the render options, length changes but situation is same. Thank you for  the clarification.

Comment: For me (on iPad 3, iOS 7.1) Test appears a bit smaller. Thus, calculated values are correct